# indexOf returns -1 for the first letter of a word

Tags: javascript, indexof

I'm trying to make a simple hangman game.
I logged the word to the console what should be guessed (this will be removed when the game is finished.)
Now I'm trying to make the player guess if the letter is in the word, if it is, it should reveal itself.

But my problem here is: I use the `indexOf()`.
The first letter of the word is -1 instead of 0,
also the letters that are not in the word are -1.
So I can't really check if it's an available letter or not since the first letter always returns -1. I added a screenshot to make it a little bit more clear.

[image: Screenshot]

notice how 'H' is the first letter of the word: Hond.
And how the alertbox says it's at the index of -1.

This is the function I used:

```
function guessLetter(letter){
    var letterVal = letter.value;

    alert(rand.indexOf(letterVal));
}
```

`rand` is the variable used for storing a random word.

Comment: It means that the letter is not contained within the word (not that the index is `-1`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first letter of the word is -1 instead of 0

No. The first letter of the word is denoted by the index `0`. If `indexOf` does not find the letter `h` in the string `Hond`, that has a different reason: it uses a case-sensitive comparison. Yielding `-1` for that case it the correct result.

For a case-insensitive search, just make sure all letters have the same casing:

```
alert(rand.toLowerCase().indexOf(letterVal.toLowerCase()) > -1
   ? "It's there"
   : "It's not there");
```

To reveal the letters that were guessed, `indexOf` doesn't seem to be the correct tool anyway. Better use something along the lines of

```
var rand = "Hond";

var guesses = [];
for ( /* every guess */ ) {
    guesses.push(guess.toLowerCase());
    var revealed = "";
    for (var i=0; i<rand.length; i++)
        if (guesses.indexOf(rand[i].toLowerCase() > -1)
            revealed += rand[i];
        else
            revealed += "_";
    }
    show(revealed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your search is case sensitive, there is no 'h' in 'Hond'. what does clicking 'o' show? it should show 1.

try converting the word to upper or lower case then compare.

Comment: if I click 'o' it shows 1. The problem is indeed the case sensitivity. Thank you! :D